# Whats the "meaning" in R of this code-chunk?

Tags: r, list, if-statement, tidyverse, na

I know there are tons of ressources out there. And I'd be superhappy to receive some indications of good ones, as it is quite difficult for a beginner to really know what's a good ressource. My question here is what's the actualy sense of the `.` and the `~` in the following code. 
I know that they encode all `-1`s and `99`s as NA. But why this complicated looking syntax?

```
mutate_all(df, list(~ifelse(. %in% c(-1, 99), NA, .)
```

So there is the `data.frame` `df` which has several columns. In all the encoding for NAs is either -1 or 99. 
I think `dplyr` also has a `na_if`-function. And wouldn't that be easier to use here?

Comment: This is syntax from the `dplyr` package that roughly translates to base `R` as the following: `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` here refers to the current column value which is equivalent to `x` in base R version of `lapply` as shared by @sindri_baldur and @Data Science.

```
lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x))
```

`~` whereas is a quosure-style lambda notation which is mostly a style preference. You can skip that and use the same syntax as `lapply` using anonymous function which would work as well.

```
dplyr::mutate_all(df, function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x))
```

In your attempt, you can also let go off `list` and use it like.

```
dplyr::mutate_all(df, ~ifelse(. %in% c(-1, 99), NA, .))
```

Answer (score 1):

They are using the `mutate_all` function to change/mutate all of the columns in the table `df` in base R you would have `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x))`

`na_if` can be used - so have a look at: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html